# Spring Webflow: How to establish my own ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource for a flow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

Spring Webflow 2.5.1.

I have my own implementation of ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource. I can successfully establish it in Spring *MVC* via:

```
    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource source = new AwareReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setCacheSeconds(cacheSeconds);
        source.setBasename("WEB-INF/i18n/messages");
        source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return source;
    }
```

My application uses both Spring *MVC* and *Webflow*.

I would like to have instances of the same AwareReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource in place for the individual per-flow messages.properties files.

I have tried:

```
@Configuration
public class WebFlowConfig extends AbstractFlowConfiguration {
  ...


    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource ms = new AwareReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        ms.setBasename("messages");

        System.out.println("MESSAGE SOURCE AwareReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource");
        return ms;
    }
}
```

But the messageSource() method is not called.

I have seen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8126164

Any pointers/techniques/code snipppets very gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Configure messageSource() within a ValidatorFactory bean, AND
2. Configure the ValidatorFactory bean within FlowBuilderServices

   @Bean
   public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices() {
   return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder()
   .setValidator(getValidator())
   .build();
   }

   @Bean
   public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
   LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
   bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
   return bean;
   }

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @sree. Sadly that didn't work for me. Hmmm. I note the doco for LocalValidatorFactoryBean  says with Spring 5, it "requires Bean Validation 1.1+". I have hibernate validator 6.1.5.FINAL. So should be good, but still. LUCKILY, I do all my  UI messaging via a single custom tag and can tweak that to do the post-processing I need. A shame, though...